# Kubernetes https communication

Tags: kubernetes

**How do I ensure that all deployed services within self managed k8 cluster should talk to each other in https only and not allow http call within?**

Comment: I guess you should add TLS certificates https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/

Answer (score 4):

Using a service mesh will make your life easier. It takes care of certificate maintenance.

Refer

- https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/mtls-migration/
- https://linkerd.io/2/features/automatic-mtls/

Comment: I am able to achieve encrypted communication  using MTLS (Istio) with in K8 cluster.thanks

Comment: If I want to use Kubernetes without using any third party tool..what is the way...?

Comment: Well you can install certificates in the pod and start the application with https

Comment: do you think this link steps are correct or u have a better post to follow - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/